# Stop Scrolling on mobile menu than allow it to start again after close

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll

Trying to Stop Scrolling on mobile menu than allow it to start again after close.
Not sure how to reverse the stopPropagation and preventDefaults.

```
function scrollFixMobile() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('mobile-menu')) {

    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

  }, false);

  } else {

  }

  }
```

Dev Link Below

http://www.alexcoven.com/dev/element

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS alone to prevent scroll using `overflow: hidden;` on `body`.

```js
$("#mobileMenu").click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("mobile-menu");
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mobileMenu">Menu</button>
<div class="container">Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>Test</br>
</div>
```

Comment: I have that in place currently and it's not working on mobile sadly ;(

http://www.alexcoven.com/dev/element